# microemulator porting for nokia x

Tags: java, android, eclipse, in-app-purchase, nokiax

I recently porting my games from `J2me` asha platform to Nokia X using `microemulator` project.
it works fine .
Now I want to know how to add `I.A.P` (in app purchasing)in my `apk` file for using in Nokia X .

I could add the project into the `Eclipse IDE` and I already build the `IAP` for nokia X in Eclipse android project separately
but when I try to run the IAP project in emulator it only shows  screen with a button and text.
and there is no activity by the button clicked. how to monetize it with any project?!! .

Is that possible to use the `xml` file to add the `Nokia IAP` in my `microemulator` project
or need more `Java` coding ?

Are there any links or samples ,,,!!!appreciate your help.

Comment: can you add some code ... you should try before asking ...

Comment: The codes are ready in IAP Nokiax project anyones could download the IAP lib and sdk from nokia .when compiled in eclipse it only showed the button without any activity .

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are no J2ME offerings for Nokia X, thus there is no IAP offerings for J2ME which you could use with Nokia X. And as far as I know Nokia store does not offer any ways on distributing J2ME apps to Nokia X, thus you can not really utilize any API even if you could get it working.

There is IAP offering for Asha devices available, but it is separate offering from the offering available for Nokia X, and the Nokia X IAP is solely targeting for Android projects, thus it is not designed to be used in J2ME, and would thus not work.

Even if you find a way to hack things together, the Nokia IAP offerings would require publishing through Nokia Store, and then you would be having the issue of the lack of possibilities of publishing the content for the platform.